# How does authentication work in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I create the controllers I make them for any non-logged / logged users with Data Annotations **[Authorize]** / **[AllowAnonymous]**.

My question is I can't figure out how to determine whether the view can be accessed with "Authorized" users or "Anonymous". Is there a way to control the access in the view?

Comment: This is incredibly broad, as how you handle said access to `Controllers`.  However, your `Controller` will dictate the access before the `View` is rendered.

Comment: Ya, but is there way to handle the access to the view by using some "good form" in MVC5? I am just trying to use what is better to the standard use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Understanding Sessions in C#

Authorized attribute and AllowAnonymous attribute are not related to Session State.

> But I can't figure out how to determine whether the view can be
>   accessed with "Authorized" users or "Anonymous". Is there a way to
>   control the access in the view?

You want to restrict access on Controller class or Action method  (not view).

By default, ASP.Net MVC uses [ASP.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity).

[Adam Freeman - Pro ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.apress.com/9781430265290?gtmf=s)  has free chapter for ASP.NET identity [here](http://www.apress.com/files/extra/ASP_NET_Identity_Chapters.pdf).

Scott Allen has free [ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamentals at PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals).

Answer (score 0):

Your controller serves up the View so decorating the specific controller which serves up whichever View will determine if Anonymous users or Authorized users can view it.

To answer your comment below about how the controller knows.  You may want to read up on how authentication works within .NET.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security

The attribute [Authorize] checks to see if an authentication cookie exists for instance.  This would be handled using something like Forms Authentication which would set an auth cookie for the user.

Comment: Okay, I get that. But how the controller knows who are the "anonymous" and the "authorized" users?

Comment: Amended my answer.  In Visual Studio you should create a new MVC project with membership and step through the code to see how the authentication process works.